# include characters UTF-8 in prompt

Tags: linux, utf-8, terminal, command-prompt

I want to include the character ` (grave accent) in the prompt.

However, I did not find any code such as \xe2\x88\x80 as I saw for other characters.

What is the corresponding code in this case?

Regards

Comment: Are you talking about a different character than the \` in ASCII?

Comment: I have tried with \x60, but with no success:

Comment: My line is PS1=$"\[\033[01;34m\]    \x60\"

Answer (score 0):

You can easily escape ` character:

```
PS1=$"[\033[01;34m] \`"
[] `
```

note: this is not utf8 char.